# how to move baked smoke domain

Tags: animation, baking, smoke-simulation

I've baked a smoke simulation and now 'm trying to animate its location but even tough the domain is moving the smoke seems to stay exactly at same location. I've tried everything: parenting it, armature deform, limit/copy location it just doesn't seem to work. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you can move a baked simulation, in this case, you have to free the bake, move the domain, and then bake again

Comment: But i want to animate it's movement not just change it

Comment: I tried to animate it. I keyed the domain location, and it moves, as expected, with baked smoke in it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was able to move the baked smoke domain w/ smoke, I had to disable "Adaptive Domain" first.

Answer (score 1):

To move the smoke you don't have to move the domain. You have to move the "flow object"

I have done a simple and basic blender file with two cubes, one named domain and the other named flow. The flow object has two location keyframes at frame 0 and 90.

Hope this replies to your question

[image]

Comment: What if I want to move the smoke? Not the "flow object". Literally move the entire domain around (local smoke)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the Adaptive Domain first