# Moving smoke animation on a more complex mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to animate a sword that bleeds black smoke that falls, and I've followed several tutorials and looked across many websites and I am unable to find a solution. I am a beginner at blender so please have patience. I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxtztAKyPU0
but have been unable to make it work for my object. I have tried parenting the domain to the object. I have tried making the domain larger, and I was even able to get the smoke effect to attach to the sword when it was not moving. My animation will consist of the sword spinning, and I want it to have a smoke trail, and then it will stand in the air and seep smoke downwards for the remainder of the animation. I have also looked for help, and the closest thing I found was this post: [how to move baked smoke domain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123307/how-to-move-baked-smoke-domain)
yet it still isn't working. I downloaded the file on this post and am trying to simulate that effect, but everything I have tried so far isn't working. I don't know if it's the nature of the mesh, or something I'm doing wrong with my animating, or some obscure trait I forgot that's messing everything up. But something is wrong with the smoke simulation, and I want to make sure it fully works the first time, rather than changing one thing and waiting 6+ hours for it to render every time I want to try something. I have even made a test file to make sure the smoke simulation is working normally, with a simple cube that expels smoke that falls, and it shows up in the object view. However, for my sword, I have separated the blade from the rest of the materials and have attached the fluid simulation to just that part, and the blade now only shows up in a wireframe view. It worked when the blade was not moving, but it does not work with the animation. I know how to do some shading and animation, but I am unable to get this simulation to work, and that is the crucial part of the whole animation. If anyone knows anything, please help me figure this out. Thank you!